# Filling array with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm absolutely struggling with jquery. 
Essentially, I have a search bar, it queries my database, and dynamically fills the dropdown box with the relevant searches (Like any decent search bar.)

Anyway, I actually don't know how to allow a user to click on of the elements to add the data to an array.  Right now, it just

```
 echo '<a href="index.php?action='.$result->game_id.'">';
```

And this works, but I want to be able to allow the user to select multiple things from the search bar.

If anyone could post some code, or point to a tutorial to help me figure this awful thing out.

Thanks.

[EDIT]

I'm sorry, I don't think I was clear enough, and thanks for the info on the whole jquery autocomplete, but I already have that!

```
if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
    $queryString = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"],$_POST['queryString']);

    // Is the string length greater than 0?
    if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
        $query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"],"SELECT * FROM gamelist WHERE name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' LIMIT 8");

        if($query) {
            // While there are results loop through them - fetching an Object.

            while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                echo '<a href="index.php?action='.$result->game_id.'">';
                echo "<img src = ".$result->image_thumb." height=46 width=46 />";

                $name = $result->name;
                echo '<span class="searchheading">'.$name.'</span>';

                 $description = $result->aliases;
                 if(strlen($description) > 80) { 
                     $description = substr($description, 0, 80) . "...";
                 }                  
                 echo '<span>'.$description.'</span></a>';
            }
            echo '<span class="seperator"><a href="http://www.marcofolio.net/sitemap.html" title="Sitemap">Nothing interesting here? Try the sitemap.</a></span><br class="break" />';
        } else {
            echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
        }
    } else {
        // Dont do anything.
    } // There is a queryString.
```

As you can see, when I get an input via _POST, the only way I can have a user interact with those results is to click the a href link.  I guess I'm only asking, what is some jQuery code that'll let me allow the user to click that, and store it back into the _POST[] array?  That way I can have them store multiple search items into the array so my PHP code can evaluate it.

I hope that was more clear.

Comment: There isn't remotely enough information here to give you a decent answer.  Can you post a sample of what you have now, and better describe what problems you are having?

Comment: jquery UI has a widget called "Autocomplete" that helps you do this.  You specify the source for the search, and it can be an AJAX endpoint - a callout to your PhP script.   jQuery's autocomplete then displays the dropdown box automatically with the matches, and lets the user cursor through the list, or click a choice. It works nicely.  Example: http://jsbin.com/ezifi

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery autocomplete has cheeso said

in the below link

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

```
  you can click on view source to see the jquery for it .
```

you can also check out the list of other jquery autocomplete plugins where you just need to pass data

http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/03/35-best-ajax-jquery-autocomplete-tutorial-plugin-with-examples/

Comment: There was an example on that second link, how to do tags.  
I'm just really not understanding how that stuff works, I think it's relying on that TextExt ajax plugin?  

But yeah, i realize now I"m asking basically how to use jQuery to make 'tags'.  That's precisely what I want.